# greedy algorithm planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

I need to order the vertexes of a planar graph so that the greedy algorithm would colour the vertexes using 6 colours.Could you please give some sugestions or hints to what could I start with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order the vertices according to their degrees and you have the Welsh-Powell alogrithm that gives a 6-coloring if the max degree is 5 or less.